# Need to find a grammar where $w\in A^*$, where $w$ consists of $n$ $a$'s followed by $n$ $b$'s, where $n\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

I need to find a grammar where $w\in A^*$, where $w$ consists of $n$ $a$'s followed by $n$ $b$'s, where $n\in\mathbb N$.

I came up with the rules
$$
\begin{align}
S&\to aSb\\
S&\to ab\\
S&\to \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Is this the right way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: just did, thank you and sorry

Answer (score 2):

More minimal

1. $S \to aSb$
2. $S \to \varepsilon$

will do. $ab$ is then a two-step derivation. But yours is fine too, minus the typo and lack of MathJax. Replace the 2 by

3. $S \to ab$

if a natural number in your definition is $\ge 1$ or not.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was also a bit conflicted, because the questions says any n. This makes me think that abbbb woud be possible too. Why is abbbb not a string? Sorry if this question is too vague.

Comment: @ano the number of a’s should equal the number of b’s   In the language.

Comment: is that a rule in context-free grammar or?

Comment: @ano no, the definition of your language.